# how to add a function to delete all the data from room in the ViewModel like this

Tags: android-architecture-components

here is the code from the Sample GithubBrowserSample

```
@OpenForTesting
class UserViewModel
 @Inject constructor(userRepository: UserRepository, repoRepository: 
 RepoRepository) : ViewModel() {
 private val _login = MutableLiveData<String>()
val login: LiveData<String>
    get() = _login
val repositories: LiveData<Resource<List<Repo>>> = Transformations
    .switchMap(_login) { login ->
        if (login == null) {
            AbsentLiveData.create()
        } else {
            repoRepository.loadRepos(login)
        }
    }
val user: LiveData<Resource<User>> = Transformations
    .switchMap(_login) { login ->
        if (login == null) {
            AbsentLiveData.create()
        } else {
            userRepository.loadUser(login)
        }
    }

fun setLogin(login: String?) {
    if (_login.value != login) {
        _login.value = login
    }
}

fun retry() {
    _login.value?.let {
        _login.value = it
    }
}
 }
```

how can I add add a function deleteAll which use the userRepository
I try to add the deleteAll() method like this but failed with unresolved reference.
fun deleteAll() {userRepository.deleteAll()}

Answer (score 0):

I should add a val before userRepository